# How can I use SUMPRODUCT AND SMALL with further conditions?

Tags: excel, filter, criteria, sumproduct

I am using this formula to sum the 10 smallest values and all is well.

=SUMPRODUCT(SMALL(G:G;ROW(INDIRECT("1:10"))))

But I would like to add a filter/condition: I only want to sum values the value in column B:B is "A" or "B".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work for you:

- `G1:G100/(B1:B100="B")` return an array of numbers in column G: G while column B:B = "B", mismatched values will return an error. so use `aggregate` to calculate their sum without `ignoring the error`, the result is a sum of 1 to 10

here's formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(AGGREGATE(15,6,G1:G100/(B1:B100="B"),ROW(1:10)))
```

[image]

Comment: Super - what if I would like to check for B or A in column B

Comment: change: `(B1:B100="B")` to `(B1:B100=if(countif(B1:B100,"A"),"A","B"))`

Comment: What does "(15,6," in the formula do?

Comment: you can see this: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-aggregate-function

Comment: @JesperKindtLarsen: It is a combination of `small and iferror functions`

Comment: One more thing: if I want to make the number of smallest values refering to cell? so instead of the value 10 I would like the value of a specific cell.

Comment: @JesperKindtLarsen change `row(1:10)` to `row(INDIRECT("A1:A"& D6))` where D6 is the cell you want to change

Comment: I get an #VALUE error here. What does A1:A refer to?

Comment: to understand `row(indirect` see this: https://exceljet.net/formula/create-array-of-numbers, if the number of `cells is equal to "B" or "A" <> D6` then an error occurs.

Comment: One last thing (I hope): need to extend the criterias fra A or B to up to 5 different letters. This will be many if's. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, maybe: change `(B1:B100="B")` to `((B1:B100="B")+(B1:B100="C")+...)`

Comment: I want to check for not only A and B, but A, B, C, D and E (so if one of these letters is in column A it should be in the sum) - Your solution work fine !

Comment: This is probably beyond your question. If I changed the answer perhaps it would not match the original question. If you haven't found the answer yet, post another question and specify what you need.

Comment: With above 1000 rows to calculate my sheet has now gotten very slow. Moving my formulas to a calculation sheet that I will update manually. Unless you have any better ideas :-)

Comment: You should not use G:G but only in limited range (G1:G ...). Also you can use VBA if you find it too slow. I think the reason is that you don't know how to optimize spreadsheets yet

Comment: Tried to limit the G column range, but it did not help much. Got any good links for optimizing excel sheets?

Comment: Got one problem: how can I avoid empty cells to be counted in the sum formula?